# Value is not transferring with GET method

Tags: javascript, php, get

Whenever I write `echo $_GET['sec'];`  then it shows the value of `sec`
but when I try the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#div_id').load('../data.php?id_to=<?php $_GET['sec'];?>')
        }, 100);
    });
```

The value of "sec", which is coming from another page does not transfer to
`data.php` with `id_to` variable.

What's wrong with my code?

I can see the value of `$_GET['sec'];` in current page but the value is not available on the `data.php` file.

Comment: is this script in a `.php` file or a `.js` file?

Comment: I'm not sure but shouldn't you use `+` before and after `sec` to concatenate it? This must be throwing error.

Comment: Possibly security issues aside, this code, as shown, should just work.

Comment: @Rajesh: Nope. That's not how php works.

Comment: your quotes are broken first off `'../data.php?id_to=<?php $_GET["sec"]; ?>'`

Comment: I think your right @rajesh, it was my first assumption.

Comment: @BrianThomas: php in a JS string. The quotes are fine.

Comment: what's the output of this php code is it ile `'../data.php?id_to=VALUE'` ?

Comment: @SUJOY ROY dont you mean this?  load(`'../data.php?id_to=' + sec`); ?
Then when you do your `$GET['sec']` on your php page, its available. 

let me know if that works and ill add it to an answer.  or Rajesh should actually

Comment: it seems syntax error ....

Comment: @BrianThomas: That is ___not___ how php works.

Comment: @Cerbrus ive been coding with php for 8 years, i know how it works, so not sure what your thinking, can you explain what i might be missing? .  This is JavaScript.  hes trying to pass a variable in javascript, to a php call.    this load is calling php right away, and the only way to pass a get variable is to pass it on the query string as `id_to=thisFrigger`, there is no get variable, unless he sends one.  Then on the PHP file, he does the $_GET['id_to'] to have access what he just sent from the javascript variable `sec`, assuming he sets it somehow (in javascripts) `var sec='thisFrigger'`

Comment: @SUJOY ROY maybe we should wait for you to come back, can you please update your question at all?

Comment: It looks like the JS here is actually _in_ a php file. In that case, just adding an `echo` is all you need to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

Code is okay so variable if available should be passed

So what can you try is:

You have simple mistake you don't echo

change `<?php $_GET['sec'];?>` to `<?php echo $_GET['sec'];?>` or `<?= $_GET['sec'] ?>`

also:

1. what's the output of this php code is it ile `'../data.php?id_to=VALUE'` If output is okay then variable will be passed via GET method
2. In your data.php try doing echo `$_GET['id_to']` maybe you try to output sec and this causes problem?
3. You can always try `print_r($_GET);` on `data.php`

Comment: didnt he mention the echo was missing in his opening point?  yeah 2 is wrong, cause he didnt echo it.  1  will give you same symptom, i.e., no workie!  3 will show you if its there or not, but you have to access it correctly.

Comment: I don't understand. I gave some symptoms that can cause problem that's all. The most possible is that he does not echo it and also he may use wrong key to get it in data.php

Answer (score -1):

You're not outputting the GET variable into your JS string.

Replace:

```
$('#div_id').load('../data.php?id_to=<?php $_GET['sec'];?>')
```

With:

```
$('#div_id').load('../data.php?id_to=<?php echo $_GET['sec'];?>')
//                         That was missing ^
```

Alternatively, there's a shorthand available for a php echo:

```
$('#div_id').load('../data.php?id_to=<?= $_GET['sec'];?>')
```

While the syntax highlighter on here may make it seem like the nested single quotes will interfere, they won't. `<?= $_GET['sec'];?>` will literally be replaced by the value in `sec`, resulting in a valid JS string.

Comment: can you really pass functioning php like that?  and WHY?  seems like an anti-pattern if there ever was one!

Comment: You've been working with php for _8_ years and _never_ realized you can do this? Seriously?

Comment: again, this is JavaScript.so kind of wierd seeing that way.  So, where is the string `sec` coming from, a second php file or something? and i mean the query string.

Comment: The script is in a `script` tag in a php file, most likely. That php file has `sec` passed to it.

Comment: AHHHHH ok, so an html file for example.  its been years since i have put php on an html file. :-)

Comment: @BrianThomas: [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8uiNDkZZQIB65NzZrwV) is what I mean. Not an html file. A `.php` file.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, yes, you named it index.html, thats whatn i mean, a .html file.  You dont want to name it with the .php extension if you have javascript on it. I havent done procedural like that for years. 

So anyway, on the answer to the problem, seems like it may have been an include issue, or where is the "query string variable" being set?  Its as if the data cant be available unless the variable is set and included, but i think the OP needs to be updated wtih more code, cause were all having fun guessing.

Comment: So, how does apache know which html to process, and which not to? _"You dont want to name it with the .php extension if you have javascript on it."_ What did you base that on? If your `home.php` has a tiny bit of JS, it doesn't suddenly become an `.html` file. The OP has a `php` tag in his JS. It's only _logical_ to assume his code _is_ in a `php` file then.

Comment: look at your plinkr, you placed your code in a .html file didnt you?  It has a `<html>` tag right and an html extension right? http://plnkr.co/edit/d8uiNDkZZQIB65NzZrwV  I am NOT talking about data.php  OK, i see your update i know it will work both ways, your right though, seeing it that way i remember i fully used to name them .php also.  sorry. Gosh how soon i forget, that was 2010.  I wish he would just show how hes passing his query string.

Comment: _*Sigh*_. Because that's the default file structure on plunker. I updated it now.

Comment: i just didnt realize it was an 'html' if you know what i mean. As opposed to NOT having ANY HTML or JS on it. as opposed to an OOP class which is the way i use PHP. Thats why i thought it was a .js file, and know you cant pass `<php $GET['anything'];` on javascript.  SO i was thrown way off.  Thanks for clarifying that, i will NEVER do that in my life again!!! (procedural php file with both html and js on that file) no code separation.

Comment: @BrianThomas: I figured as much.

Comment: i gotta LOL that one. Cerebus, your definitely right then about echoing it, it needs to be echoed, @SUJOY ROY you were Not echoing it, so it wouldn't print on the string. Good call cerbrus.  upvote..

Comment: -2? What's with the downvotes? What's _wrong_ with this answer?

Comment: I have been having this problem, i think the community should SEPARATE the scores from down votes between,  A) when the question is just lame and needs editing, in which maybe it should automatically go back up to atleast 0  upon moderation review

Comment: and B) when its just SO politics the moderation should not cost in the down vote of the post, but separately (maybe even next to it, but separately).  Personal e.g., One time I made editors mad about my preference freedom of punctuation, and they all down voted my quality merely post due to lower case issues, un-rightful & petty IMO. I was just in linux clothing at the time.  That kind of moderation stuff should be lefi off the OP down vote count IMO.  Its been a hard road up here!  Is it like that for everyone?  Doubtful, but whats the percentage?